# How to read column names and metadata from feather files in R arrow?

Tags: r, apache-arrow, feather

The (now-superseded) stand-alone [feather library for R](https://github.com/wesm/feather) had a function called `feather_metadata()` that allowed to read column names and types from feather files on disk, without opening them.
This was useful to select only specific columns when loading a feather file in R with `read_feather(path, columns = c(...))`

Now that the feather format is part of the [arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/index.html) library, `feather_metadata()` is not included anymore.

Is there an equivalent function in arrow to read column names and types of files on disk from R before loading them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of the arrow R package, there is no direct replacement for `feather::feather_metadata(path)`, but there are two workarounds that might work for you:

- If you just need the column names (not the data types), you can do this:

  ```r
  rf <- arrow::ReadableFile$create(path)
  fr <- arrow::FeatherReader$create(rf)
  names(fr)
  ```
- If you need the data types of the columns, you can try this:

  ```r
  arrow::read_feather(path, as_data_frame = FALSE)
  ```

  That gives output like what you're looking for, and it should be pretty fast (because it does *not* convert the file to an R data frame) but it does read the full file (or at least it memory-maps the full file) so you might not want to do this if your Feather files are really large.

Comment: Is there a similar way to do this with parquet files that have partions?

Comment: Yes, you can use [arrow::open_dataset()](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/open_dataset.html) to open multi-file datasets optionally with partitioning. It does not read the files from disk.